# Response from Ajax.BeginForm not getting with textbox value

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having some trouble with ajax. I have two datepickers and a button. While pressing the button, values in the datepicker textbox need to be passed to controller action method through `Ajax.BeginForm()` method and display a partial view. But when I press the button nothing happens.  Here is the code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomerFilter(string fromDate, string toDate)
{            
    IEnumerable<DC_MASTERReport> dcms = null;    
    try
    {                
        dcms = from t in db.DC_ITEM
               join t0 in db.DC_MASTER on t.DC_NO equals t0.DC_NO
               .....
               where
                 t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE == t1.ITEM_CODE && (DateTime.ParseExact(t0.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null).Date.CompareTo(fromDate) >= 0 && DateTime.ParseExact(t0.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null).Date.CompareTo(toDate) <= 0)                                             
               select new DC_MASTERReport
               {
                   DC_NO = t0.DC_NO,
                   DC_STYPE = t0.DC_STYPE,
                   ....                          
                };
        return PartialView("DeliveryList", dcms);                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "Some error occured while loading the page contact help desk";
        ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "Delivery-CustomerFilter-POST");
        return PartialView("DeliveryList", dcms);
    }
}
```

My Initial View - Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CustomerFilter", "Delivery", new System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "deliverylist"
     }))
{               
    <input id="fromDate" name="fromDate" type="text" />
    <input id="toDate" name="toDate" type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="View" id="BtnSubmit" text="Proceed" runat="server" />
}

// Delivery List Partial View
<div id="deliverylist">
    @Html.Partial("DeliveryList")
</div>

// Java script for Date Picker
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $("#fromDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        $("#toDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

        $("#toDate").change(function () {
            var fromDate = $("#fromDate").val();
            if (fromDate == '') {
                alert("Please select From Date");
                return false;
            }           
        });
    });
</script>
```

`DeliveryList.cshtml` is the Partial View.

Actually, is this the correct way of using `Ajax.BeginForm()` method

Comment: Your submitting dates so start by changing your parameters in the method to `DateTime` not `string` and remove `runat="server"` from your button (its MVC, not Web Forms). Are you getting any errors? Is it actually hitting the controller method?

Comment: Why would you store dates as `varchar` (you should consider changing that). And I have edited out all the irrelevant html, but using tables for layout, especially nested table is awful practice. Your problem is probably that you have `<input type="button" ... >`. It should be  `<input type="submit" ... />`

Comment: Are you sure you have no errors in the browser console (the view code looks fine)

Comment: That suggests your returning an empty model. Debug your code to check `dcms` is not `null` and actually include the values you expect. If it is, then you need to show your partial view code.